# In data.table, find events that have other type of events between them

Tags: r, data.table

I have two types of timed events - those with a single coordinate ("points") and continuous ones ("lines") having `start` and `stop`. For each pair of consecutive points, I need to find if there is any line between or overlaping with them. For example:
[image]
Here, there is no lines between points `B` and `C` while all other pairs have some lines between them or overlapping with them.

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- fread('
id subject type start stop
 a subjA   line   11    17
 b subjA   line   24    25
 c subjA   line   28    30
 d subjA   line   29    32
 A subjA   pt     16    
 B subjA   pt     19
 C subjA   pt     22
 D subjA   pt     27
 E subjA   pt     29
 F subjA   pt     32
 X subjB   pt      1
', fill=T)
```

I am trying to play with `foverlaps()` and can mark single points that overlap with lines, but that's not what I need - to find lines *between* points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `foverlaps` here and consider both have a start and stop value, "lines" directly, but the points also as you are interested in the start of A, where the end is the start of B, etc.

```
dtR <- dt1[type == "line"]
dtP <- dt1[type == "pt"]

dtP <- dtP[, stop := shift(start, type = "lead"), subject][, fromto := paste0(id, shift(id, type = "lead")), subject][!is.na(stop)]

setkey(dtR, subject, start, stop)
setkey(dtP, subject, start, stop)

merge(
  dtP[, .(subject, fromto)],
  foverlaps(dtR, dtP)[, .SD[1], .(subject, fromto)][, 1:2][, result := "yes"],
  all = T
)[is.na(result), result := "no"][]

#    subject fromto result
# 1:   subjA     AB    yes
# 2:   subjA     BC     no
# 3:   subjA     CD    yes
# 4:   subjA     DE    yes
# 5:   subjA     EF    yes
```